# Why does my timepicker do not work using React and Tailwind CSS?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, datetimepicker, timepicker

I tried to use that timepicker using React.js and Tailwind CSS :

https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/forms/timepicker/

The code was the following :

```
<div class="flex justify-center">
  <div class="timepicker relative form-floating mb-3 xl:w-96">
    <input type="text"
      class="form-control block w-full px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
      placeholder="Select a date" />
    <label for="floatingInput" class="text-gray-700">Select a time</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I cannot click on the timepicker to set the hour.

Here is my project :

[My project](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-franklin-wsdf6u?file=/public/index.html)

Could you help me please ?

Thnak you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the correct dependency in the code sandbox.

Rather, if this is any project or part of it, I would suggest you work in the local environment and install the npm package by following [these](https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/)
steps.

Secondly, if this is for illustration or learning purposes then you can use the `tailwind-element snippet` from [here](https://tailwind-elements.com/snippets/).

Comment: I tried what you said but without any success :/

Comment: Which of the above two methods you tried?